# Why there is no output in console?the code in the block of IO#realines methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby

This seems really strange to me:

```
f = File.open(Dir.pwd+'/tmp','r') 
f.readlines do |l|
  puts "#{f.lineno}:#{l}"
end

#=>["first line","second"]
```

why there is no output in the console like

```
1: first line
2: second line
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `each` and not `readlines`.

```
File.open(Dir.pwd+'/tmp','r') do |f|
  f.each do |l|
    puts "#{f.lineno}:#{l}"
  end
end
```

`readlines` reads the whole array at once.

In your particular case, you called `readlines` to get an array, but you passed a block to the `readlines` method.  The method `readlines` just returns an array, it does not process a block.  You should only supply a block to a method call that knows how to handle a block.  If the method cannot process a block, nothing happens.

(Aside: If you do an `each` on the result of `readlines` then you will get the same line number on each line.)

Comment: Thanks I was so careless to read to description, readlines just can't take block